# How do I log out of Facebook with the Silverlight In-Browser Sample?

Tags: silverlight, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk, logout

I'm using the CS-SL4-InBrowser sample project that was provided with the Facebook C# SDK.  This is a Silverlight in browser sample that uses OAuth

The Facebook login process uses FacebookOAuthClient.GetLoginUrl() which works well.

However, there does not seem to be an equivalent method for retrieving the logout url (eg. FacebookOAuthClient.GetLogoutUrl() ).

Can anyone suggest the correct method for logging out or point me to a post that might help?